# javascript regex to match braces with line breaks, but not without

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying, in javascript, to get a regexp to match areas contained by curly braces (and including) in a string where there are one or more line breaks, and possible tag nesting. So it would match `{the quick brown fox ... lazy dog}` inside the string:

```
did you know {the quick brown fox
jumps

over the lazy dog} is a pangram?
```

but not the curly braced area inside the following string, as it doesn't contain a line break

```
did you know {the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog} is a pangram?
```

I'm coming unstuck when there is nesting, because I want only `brown \n fox` to match in the following example, since it is the immediate brace containing the line break.

```
did you know {the quick {brown
fox} jumps over the lazy dog} is
a pangram?
```

the obvious `/\{([^{]+)\}/g` will match anything inside a curly set, but that can mean it can erroneously match on `{the quick {brown \n fox}` and `{brown \n fox} jumps over the lazy dog}`. I'm starting to think that substring matching might be the way, something like the way a css template system like [mustache js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js) does it.

Answer (score 4):

To ensure there are at least one newline char in the string, use the regex like below:

```
/\{(?=.*\n)[^}]+\}/
```

*console:*

```
> "aaa{ccc}bbb".match(/\{(?=.*\n)[^}]+\}/)
  null
> "aaa{ccc\ndddd}bbb".match(/\{(?=.*\n)[^}]+\}/)
  ["{ccc
  dddd}"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will work `/\{(?=.*\s)[^{}]+\}/`

From console

```
a = "aa{aaaa
bb}b"
b = "aaaa{cccc}bbb"
c = "aaaaaaa{sssss{ddd
dd}bbb}sss"

a.match(/\{(?=.*\s)[^{}]+\}/)
["{aaaa
bb}"]
b.match(/\{(?=.*\s)[^{}]+\}/)
null
c.match(/\{(?=.*\s)[^{}]+\}/)
["{ddd
dd}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
   \{([^{\n]+)\}
```

I tested it here: http://regex101.com/r/vJ6gU1

Comment: @frumbert Maybe I missunderstood question: You do actually want to match linebreaks in your string just not `\n` literally? This regex will match anything within brackets but not linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
/\{[^{}\n]*\n[^{}]*\}/
```

`[^{}\n]*\n` consumes everything up to the next linefeed, but it fails if it sees a brace first.

Then `[^{}]*` consumes the rest because it doesn't matter if there are any more linefeeds.

I'm assuming your line separators consist of linefeed alone (`\n`) or carriage return plus linefeed (`\r\n`).  There are some other possibilities, but they're very rare.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for your string:

```
 "did you know {the quick {brown\nfox} jumps over the lazy dog} is\na pangram?"
.match(/\{[^{}]+\}/)
```

Returns `{brown\nfox}`.

`/\{[^{}]+\}/`:

1. Match a `{`.
2. Match everything that's not a `{` or `}`.
3. Match a `}`

#### [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cC2iJ8)

Comment: The match part should have one newline char at least.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed :(

Answer (score 0):

This will work Try it

```
\{([^{]+?)\}
```